# Display only top sum-up results using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

My table records three different scores (site, park, division) for the same group of user. 
A user's total score is "sum of all the site scores" + "sum of all the park scores" + "sum of all the division scores".

The code is the following and I am using MySQL:

```
select  sum(points)as points, user_name 
from 
(SELECT sum(site_point) as points, user_name from visits v join users u on 
u.user_id = v.user_id group by user_name
union 
select sum(park_point) as points , user_name  from visits v join users u on                 
u.user_id = v.user_id group by user_name
union
select sum(division_point) as points , user_name  from visits v join users u 
on u.user_id = v.user_id  group by user_name
) V group by user_name  order by sum(points) DESC ;
```

I want to display only the users whose score is in top 5 and their scores.
Ten users may have the same highest score. I need all of them being displayed.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't need the `UNION`. Just use `SELECT SUM(site_point + park_point + division_point) AS points`

Comment: Add `LIMIT 5` to show the top 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select user_name,
       sum(site_point + park_point + division_point) as points
from visits v join
     users u
     on u.user_id = v.user_id
group by user_name
order by points desc
limit 5;
```

A single aggregation simplifies the calculation.

You may not realize it, but the `union` is going to return incorrect results under some circumstances.  `Union` removes duplicates, so if a user has the same partial scores, then the two rows becomes one.

EDIT:

It is a little trickier to get the top 5 *scores*, but possible:

```
select user_name,
       sum(site_point + park_point + division_point) as points
from visits v join
     users u
     on u.user_id = v.user_id
group by user_name
having points >= (select distinct points
                  from (select sum(site_point + park_point + division_point)
                        from visits v join
                             users u
                             on u.user_id = v.user_id
                        group by user_name
                       ) vu
                  order by points desc
                  limit 1 offset 4
                 )
order by points desc
limit 5;
```

Assuming that a `user_name` is unique for a given id you can simplify this a wee bit:

```
having points >= (select distinct points
                  from (select sum(site_point + park_point + division_point) as points
                        from visits v 
                        group by user_id
                       ) vu
                  order by points desc
                  limit 1 offset 4
                 )
```

And, if you want anyone who matches the top 5 users -- but to return more than 5 rows if there are ties -- then change the `select distinct` to `select` in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I need a little more help here. What I want is displaying the top 5 scores and the corresponding users. Ten users may have the same highest score. I need all of them being displayed.

Comment: I am having a SQL syntax error near "order by points desc
                                                            offset 4 limit 1". I can't find out why.

Comment: @Tudoctrine . . . That's my bad.  ANSI requires that `OFFSET` goes *before* `FETCH FIRST`.  I tend to forget that databases using `LIMIT` requires that it go *after*.

Comment: Sorry, I am asking a lot. I have an error "Reference points not supported (reference to group function)" now with your updated code. It has something to do with column aliases. I am figuring it out.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff.. I have figured it out. it should be "select sum(site_point + park_point + division_point)  as points" in the subquery. Your code is missing "as points". I also removed the "Limit 5" at the very end because the scores can be tied, the result will be more than 5 rows.  Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LIMIT` command. More info [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php)

So to tack it onto your SQL would result in:

```
select  sum(points)as points, user_name 
from 
(SELECT sum(site_point) as points, user_name from visits v join users u on 
u.user_id = v.user_id group by user_name
union 
select sum(park_point) as points , user_name  from visits v join users u on                 
u.user_id = v.user_id group by user_name
union
select sum(division_point) as points , user_name  from visits v join users u 
on u.user_id = v.user_id  group by user_name
) V group by user_name  order by sum(points) DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My apology, I wasn't quite clear on my question initially. I need more than 5 records because the top 5 scores can be shared by many different users.